# ReactJS img not updating after API Call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

Im learning React right now and trying to wrap my head around why my other components updated the information but my img tag has not after the second API call.

Here's my code:

```
export default function LandingPage() {

    const [zipcode, setZipCode] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState();
    var [cityWeatherData, setCityWeatherData] = useState([]);
    var [forecast, setForcast] = useState([]);

   return(
 
<TextField 
  label='Zip Code' 
  value={zipcode} 
  onChange={(e) => { setZipCode(e.target.value) }} />
     <Button
       sx={{ ml: 3, backgroundColor: '#5F8FFF', color: 'white', '&:hover': { color: '#5F8FFF' } }}
      
       onClick={ () => {
           currentWeather(zipcode, apiKey)
           .then( async (result) => {
               setLoading(true);
               await sevenDayWeather(result['coord']['lon'], result['coord']['lat'], apiKey)
                      .then( (response)  => {
                                response['daily'].forEach( (day) => {
                                    console.log('day forecast: ', day);
                                    console.log('Day Weather: ', day['weather'][0]['icon']);
                                    setForcast( forecast => [...forecast, day['weather'][0]['icon']]);
                                })
                            });
                        });
                    }}>
      Search
    </Button>
     
    {loading ?
        // console.log('forecast: ', forecast)
            <WeatherBox
                apiKey={apiKey}
                name={weatherData['name']}
                lat={weatherData['coord']['lat']}
                lon={weatherData['coord']['lon']}
                feelsLike={weatherData['main']['feels_like']}
                highestTemp={weatherData['main']['temp_max']}
                lowestTemp={weatherData['main']['temp_min']}
                forecast={forecast}
            /> : <></>}
);}
```

For my `WeatherBox` component

```
export default function WeatherBox(props) {
let newDate = new Date()
let date = newDate.getDate();
let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
let year = newDate.getFullYear();
return (
    <Box
        className='retrievedInformation'
        sx={{
            mt: 10,
            p: 5,
            boxShadow: 'gray 5px 10px 10px 5px',
            borderRadius: '20px',
            textAlign: 'end',
            backgroundImage: `url(${sunny})`,
            objectFit: 'contain',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundSize: '500px 500px'
        }}>
        <Typography
            sx={{ fontSize: '50px' }}>
            {props.name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography
            sx={{ fontSize: '25px' }}>
            Today:  {month} / {date} / {year}
        </Typography>
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[0]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
        <Box
            display='flex'
            flexDirection='row'
            sx={{ textAlign: 'end', justifyContent: 'end', alignItems: 'end' }}>
            <Typography
                sx={{ mr: 3, fontSize: '30px', fontWeight: '300', color: 'gray' }}>
                Feels Like:
            </Typography>
            <Typography
                sx={{ fontSize: '30px' }}>
                {props.feelsLike} F
            </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box
            display='flex'
            flexDirection='row'
            justifyContent='end'
            alignItems='end'
            sx={{ textAlign: 'end' }}>
            <Typography
                sx={{ mr: 3, fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: '300', color: 'gray', textAlign: 'end' }}>
                Highest Temperature:
            </Typography>
            <Typography
                sx={{ fontSize: '20px', textAlign: 'end' }}>
                {props.highestTemp} F
            </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box
            display='flex'
            flexDirection='row'
            justifyContent='end'
            alignItems='end'>
            <Typography sx={{ mr: 3, fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: '300', color: 'gray', textAlign: 'end' }}>Lowest Temperature: </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '20px', textAlign: 'end' }}> {props.lowestTemp} F</Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box textAlign='end' alignItems='end' justifyContent='end'>
            <Typography sx={{ mt: 5, fontSize: '30px' }}>Weather forecast for the next 7 days</Typography>
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[1]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[2]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[3]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[4]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[5]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[6]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[7]}@2x.png`} alt='forecast image' />
        </Box>
    </Box>
);
}
```

My `forecast` array has been update as well and holding all the correct values however, the img tag in `weatherbox` is still not updating

Thanks for your help in advance

EDIT: Added link to codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-thunder-u76vwt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the code. Sure, some things could be tightened up or improved, but it looks like the `forecast` state is updated and should trigger a rerender. Could you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? If you don't want to share the `apiKey` in the box then please just provide valid example responses.

Comment: Hey there Drew! Thank you for your response. Here's the link to the code sandbox (sorry for the long file as I tried to put everything in one place) [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-thunder-u76vwt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @DrewReese for the API key you can use `66a3916c247a96eb0e2f549d1e6da0e8` but for whatever reason when I tested in there it gave me a 401 invalid API key error but it's fine as seen in this [Link](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=91001,us&appid=66a3916c247a96eb0e2f549d1e6da0e8&units=imperial). You can get one here too from [Open Weather](https://openweathermap.org/)

Comment: I had to comment out `backgroundImage: \`url(${sunny})\`,` since `sunny isn't declared. Odd, it worked a few times for me, then it returned the 401. When it worked though, I got a valid response back and your UI rendered without issue, the images all worked. I created my own key but still see a 401. I wonder if there's an issue with trying to do this from a codesandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for testing out the code for me. The img tag loads all the images fine for the first call however, the problem is that when I do another zipcode and clicked search, the texts updated, but the img tag (the weather images) did not update ( i.e. first search 91001 everything looks great, searched again for 95133, name changed to San Jose but the weather forecast images did not update from 91001's to 95133's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

> The img tag loads all the images fine for the first call however, the
> problem is that when I do another zipcode and clicked search, the
> texts updated, but the img tag (the weather images) did not update (
> i.e. first search 91001 everything looks great, searched again for
> 95133, name changed to San Jose but the weather forecast images did
> not update from 91001's to 95133's)

You always append forecast data to the `forecast` state but only reference the first 8 elements.

```
response["daily"].forEach((day) => {
  setForcast((forecast) => [
    ...forecast, // <-- shallow copy persists old forecast data
    day["weather"][0]["icon"]
  ]);
});
```

...

```
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[0]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>

...

<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[1]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[2]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[3]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[4]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[5]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[6]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
<img
  src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.forecast[7]}@2x.png`}
  alt="forecast image"
/>
```

## Solution

To resolve, you should overwrite the forecast state when updating.

```
setForcast(response.daily.map((day) => day.weather[0].icon));
```

Here's a "optimized" button click handler.

```
<Button
  onClick={async () => {
    setLoading(false);

    const weather = await currentWeather(zipcode, apiKey);
    setWeatherData(weather);
    console.log(weather);

    const forecast = await sevenDayWeather(
      weather.coord.lon,
      weather.coord.lat,
      apiKey
    );
    setForcast(forecast.daily.map((day) => day.weather[0].icon));

    setLoading(true);
  }}
>
  Search
</Button>
```

And for the sake of **DRY**-ness, mapped forecast images.

```
{props.forecast.map((id, index) => (
  <img
    key={index}
    src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${id}@2x.png`}
    alt="forecast image"
  />
))}
```

Comment: the DRY part I actually had a similar code for that but for whatever reason the src part always searched for `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d,04n,02d,01d,01d,03d,02d@2x.png` ie the whole forecast array which is why I manually typed it all out instead

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs Welcome. I had actually already fixed that in a fork of your codesandbox but couldn't reliably get the apiKey to work, yours or mine, but after your last comment I knew immediately what you were referring to.